# Is there a way to edit the source of a network request in Firebug?

Tags: firebug

Can the source of the *Post* tab of a specific POST request in Firebug's *Net* panel be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug up to version 2.x does not allow to edit network requests. There is a [longstanding enhancement request for this](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/2487).

Though [Firebug 3](http://getfirebug.com/releases/firebug/3.0/) is designed to integrate into the Firefox built-in devtools. And they already allow to edit network requests and resend them. So it will inherit this feature from them.

To do that you need to select a request within the *Network* panel, then click *Edit and Resend*, edit the parameters and click on *Send*.